# Increase font size by character length using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

Hellow, I was wondering how could I increase the font size by using as reference the characters length. What I'm trying to do is some kind of information post, which can (or not) have images, now, when a user only place text the height of the post is critical damaged in size (because of the randomness of characters the user inputs), so I was trying to develop this thing in which if the user put only text on the post the font could grow until the maximums height of the post is reached (650px) taking on consideration the characters, so few characters=bigger font, lot of characters= small font(until reach maximum font size). basically I want to find the font growing ratio by characters used.

Things to have in consideration:

- The width is not important for this purpose.
- For this purpose I cannot decrease the height of the post, has to be
  650 px.
- The maximum characters the post can has without damaging the height
  is: 1202 characters and 10.5px
- I know that the post require of a min length of characters to doesn't
  look weird by the size incrementation.

If I din't explain my self correctly, please tell me, I would really appreciate this one, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would change the font size depending on length :

```js
function changeFontSize() {

  var thisVal = $('#input').val(); //get input value
  $('#output').text(thisVal); //change <p> text to input text
  var fontSize = 300/thisVal.length; //alter font size depending on string length
  $('#output').css("font-size", fontSize + "px"); //set font size
  
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input id='input' onchange='changeFontSize()' onkeyup='changeFontSize()'> 
<p id='output'>
</p>
</div>
```

The rest should be fairly easy to implement :)

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9m62qyxa/

Comment: perfect and short solution :) ty